# RegEx phone number doesn't match

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match following formats:

```
06142/898-301
+49 6142 898-301
```

with this

```
(([+][\d]{2}[ ])|0)([\d]{4}/)([/d]{2,}[.-])+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/U_rBvh8JE3F9MGQp)

But after the area code before the `/` it won't match anymore. Why?

Comment: You should give RegexBuddy a try btw, it's extremely helpful for building regex statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want something more like this:

```
^(\+\d{2} |0)\d{4}[/ ]\d{3}[.-]\d{3}$
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/qG2zY2

You don't need character classes defined for a single character, and you probably don't need all the capture groups either. I also added the anchor characters in there (^, $) but you can remove them if you're trying to pick this out of a larger string.

Answer (score 1):

you mean this?

```
(([+][\d]{2}[ ])|0)([\d]{4}/)([\d]{2,}[.-])+
```

what I changed in your expression:

```
[/d]{2,} - > [\d]{2,}  actually \d{2,} would do too
```